# PHP and DOMDocument removeNode leaves blank lines

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have a dom document and I am removing some elements with:

```
$originalItems = $doc->getElementsByTagName('original');

for ($i = 0; $i < $originalItems->length; $i++) {

    $originalItem = $originalItems->item($i);
    $originalItem->parentNode->removeChild($originalItem);
    $i--;
}
```

The problem is that this is leaving blank lines there where the element was removed.
Any idea on how to avoid that, or remove those blank lines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using preserveWhiteSpace before loading the xml

```
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
```